# Open an Access database to a particular report rather than a table?

Tags: ms-access, report, default

whenever we open up a particular database, it opens to a table and then we have to open up the report we work from. For security reasons, we'd like the database to open to a particular report rather than the default table. Is there a way to change the database's behavior to open a record by default? Perhaps through a command line switch? In this particular case, we'd want to open a report named "01 Dashboard" by default upon opening the database.

Also note, we are on Windows 10, running Office 365.

Thank you.

Comment: You can open to a specific Form pretty easily in the options, but without code not to a specific report.  My suggestion would be to open a form that launches your report.  on a side note - your end users should never have direct access to a table, bad things come from that.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [AutoExec](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-98ba1508-dcc6-4e0f-9698-a4755e548124) macro that opens the report.

Or edit the existing one (or the VBA code it calls), if it really is a table that is automatically opened, and not a form in datasheet view.